# removing duplicate geometries using two unequal geodataframes

Tags: python, geopandas

I am having a issue in identifying/removing duplicate geometries using two geodataframes.
I have two geodataframes which have unequal records and coz of that I think I cannot use **isin**

my messy solution

```
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd

#reading files
orthostrips = gpd.read_file('thefilename.shp') #df1
result_intersection = gpd.overlay(orthostrips,orthostrips, how='intersection') #df2

#delete those polygons from self intersection file which are identical to original orthostrips i.e. duplicates
indexes_discard = []
for i,row in result_intersection.iterrows():
    for i_,row_ in orthostrips.iterrows():
        if row.geometry == row_.geometry:
            indexes_discard.append(i)
#result
result_intersection.drop(result_intersection.index[indexes_discard], inplace=True )
```

the above code works totally fine when applying on subset data, but gets insanely slow on whole dataset ~58000 records. is there some other solution that could speed up the process.

my final goal is to give a polygon geodataframe as input, check for the intersecting polygons, output a polygons dataframe with intersecting polygons only.

any help would be highly appreciated
Thanks in advance

#ALTERNATE SOLUTION
i managed to achieve it with spatial joins but if someone has some better solution using spatial indexes or something, they are welcome to answer

```
result_intersection = gpd.overlay(orthostrips,orthostrips, how='intersection')                    
del_strips = gpd.sjoin(result_intersection, orthostrips, how = 'inner', predicate = 'contains' )
overlap_area_raw = result_intersection.drop(del_strips.index)
```

Comment: have you looked at `sjoin()` ?

Comment: yeah i managed it somehow with sjoin. i have edited the post to add that bit